# Return to requested page after external authentication

Tags: angularjs, spring

So I have an application that uses external authentication. Having something like:

```
public class MyFilter extends GenericBeanFilter {
...

    doFilter (...) {
        if (needAuth) {
            String url = request.getRequestURL();
            // some code that saves this url to use after login
            response.sendRedirect();
            return;
        }
    }
```

My current problem is that after authentication user is returned to default page.
This is because first requested URL in this class is always '{host}/index.html'.
This seems to be quite usual situation, but I cant find anything about it.

What I think is happening if I remove athentication:
1. Browser makes call i.e. {host}/country/city
2. Something in Spring handles this request and perform some kind of redirect, so:
3. Browser makes call {host}/index.html
   Browser makes calls {host}/*.js
   ...
4. Angularjs makes call {host}/country/city

## So may be, the question is who handles the very first request in Spring?

May be all above is because URL I use caontains #: 'localhost/#/groups'... Even with turned off server, chrome make first call to just 'localhost'. (For 'localhost/groups' first call is 'localhost/groups') Hmm...

Comment: So your question is that what component of spring handles each request head first, or is it how to handle the redirection that happens from the spring filter in AngularJS code ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you talk about redirecting to requested page. Do you mean the Angular route?:

```
index.html/#/whatever
```

If so, then I don't think spring takes care of fragments (the stuff after #). You'll have to manually pass the Angular route to your server, in order to re-direct the user once they're logged in.

Comment: unfortunately, for unknown reason i didnt understand this first time i read it -(

Answer (score 1):

You need to use in one request an information that existed in previous one. As HTTP is a not connected protocol, it is not directly available.

IMHO, you should use a session attribute to store the initial requested URL before redirecting to login page. Then after successful authentication, you can redirect to the saved URL that is available in session, and then removes it from session.

The algorythme is straightforward :

- before redirection to login :

  - if the requested page is *special* (login, logout) but passes through the filter do not save it
  - if something as already saved (the attribute exists and is not empty) : leave it unchanged
  - else store requested URL
- after successful authentication :

  - if the session attribute exists and is not empty, redirect to the saved URL
  - else redirect to a default URL (`/index.html`)

You could also use alternatives, such as pass the saved URL in a parameter of the initial redirection, or manage all at the angular level with the spring application that would not redirect but only gives a *non authenticated* response. But IMHO the session attribute is simpler to implement in your spring application